# How to get output of any command run inside k8 POD to stout?

Tags: kubernetes, logging, kubernetes-pod, top-command

My requirement is that in my POD  multiple processes are running and I want to collect the metrices for all the processes i.e (CPU AND MEMORY and other details OF all Process). Now , I want to write the output of any command I run inside my pod to stout .

Comment: Hi beingumang, since not every container has linux 'top' program inside, do you mean that you want to write the same metrics as 'kubectl top' outputs?

Comment: I want to get the output of any command which I run inside my POD to stout. How can I do that ? I can run top inside my pod or anyother command , goal is to get the output of that command in stout .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A container engine handles and redirects any output generated to a containerized application's `stdout` and `stderr` streams. For example, the Docker container engine redirects those two streams to a logging driver, which is configured in Kubernetes to write to a file in JSON format.

Usually, it is PID1 process's stdout and stderr.
So, try the following command inside a k8s Pod:

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo >> /proc/1/fd/1
```

Then you will see the standard output in the pod's logs:

```
$ kubectl logs yourPodName
...
MemTotal:       12807408 kB
MemFree:        10283624 kB
MemAvailable:   11461168 kB
Buffers:           50996 kB
Cached:          1345376 kB
...
```

To write `stdout` and `stderr` from the command, run it like this:

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo 1>> /proc/1/fd/1 2>> /proc/1/fd/2
```